# How to interpret document.state == 12 (iCloud)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, icloud, uidocument

Whenever I load a UIDocument from iCloud, I check its state like so:

```
NSLog(@"Library loadFromContents: state = %d", self.documentState);
```

In some cases I have received documentState 8 or 12 which have caused crashes. I am now wondering what exactly the 8 and 12 stands for. As far as I'm aware, documentState is a bit field, so it has many different flags. The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html) reveal that:

```
enum {
UIDocumentStateNormal          = 0,
UIDocumentStateClosed          = 1 << 0,
UIDocumentStateInConflict      = 1 << 1,
UIDocumentStateSavingError     = 1 << 2,
UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled = 1 << 3   }; 
typedef NSInteger UIDocumentState;
```

However, I have no idea how to interpret this in my situation. How do I find out what 8 and 12 stand for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the enum they do some bit-shifting. They could have also written it like this:

```
enum {
UIDocumentStateNormal          = 0,
UIDocumentStateClosed          = 1,
UIDocumentStateInConflict      = 2,
UIDocumentStateSavingError     = 4,
UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled = 8   }; 
typedef NSInteger UIDocumentState;
```

A bit shift to the left is basically 2 to the power of whatever number is given after the shift operator... 1<<1 means 2^1, 1<<2 means 2^2, etc ...

A state of 8 means `UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled` and 12 means `UIDocumentStateEditingDisabled` and `UIDocumentStateSavingError`

Comment: Thanks so much for this very lucid explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way to deal with these notifications is to **not** check for `if(state == UIDocumentStateInConflict)` but with a logical AND like this:

```
if (state & UIDocumentStateInConflict) {
    // do something...
}
```

see ["An Example: Letting the User Pick the Version" in "Document-based app programming guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ResolveVersionConflicts/ResolveVersionConflicts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH6-SW7) from the official docs